# Pycharm issues with installing Setuptools

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, setuptools

I have recently played around with different versions of Python 2.7 and I ended up breaking PyCharm.
Firstly I have uninstalled and reinstalled Python and Pycharm multiple times with no luck.

I get the feeling that setup tools is the main issue but I can't seem to get it uninstalled correctly...

Below is the error Pycharm is giving and I am seeing similar errors trying to fix setuptools manually.

Anybody have a clue what is wrong with my environment?

```
Install package failed. 

The following command was executed:

c:\users\ask\appdata\local\temp\tmpf3zyjdpycharm-management\setuptools-1.1.5\setup.py install

The error output of the command:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ask\appdata\local\temp\tmpf3zyjdpycharm-management\setuptools-1.1.5\setup.py", line 204, in <module>
    dist = setuptools.setup(**setup_params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\ask\appdata\local\temp\tmpf3zyjdpycharm-management\setuptools-1.1.5\setuptools\command\install.py", line 73, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "c:\users\ask\appdata\local\temp\tmpf3zyjdpycharm-management\setuptools-1.1.5\setuptools\command\install.py", line 82, in do_egg_install
    easy_install = self.distribution.get_command_class('easy_install')
  File "c:\users\ask\appdata\local\temp\tmpf3zyjdpycharm-management\setuptools-1.1.5\setuptools\dist.py", line 363, in get_command_class
    self.cmdclass[command] = cmdclass = ep.load()
  File "c:\users\ask\appdata\local\temp\tmpf3zyjdpycharm-management\setuptools-1.1.5\pkg_resources.py", line 2108, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "c:\users\ask\appdata\local\temp\tmpf3zyjdpycharm-management\setuptools-1.1.5\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 34, in <module>
    from setuptools.sandbox import run_setup
  File "c:\users\ask\appdata\local\temp\tmpf3zyjdpycharm-management\setuptools-1.1.5\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 209, in <module>
    _EXCEPTIONS.append(GetGeneratePath())
  File "win32com\client\gencache.pyc", line 131, in GetGeneratePath
AssertionError: Why do you want the genpath for a readonly store?
```

Comment: Is it failing when installing an egg? Are you missing write permissions to the PYTHONPATH?

Comment: I can't decide if its pip or setuptools... :(

Comment: When I try to install packages with PyCharm its giving this error message :      packaging_tool.py install --build-dir C:\Users\ask\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging6316666239942030572.tmp --user Flask

The error output of the command:


DEPRECATION: --no-install, --no-download, --build, and --no-clean are deprecated.  See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/906.       Could this be a pip issue?

Comment: deprecation is not an error, but a warning

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally managed to get this resolved. I installed a library called Automa about the same time I started getting the issue. With the install I had to add a PYTHONPATH entry and when I removed it today setup tools was able to install again.

I have added the PYTHONPATH back again and I am still able to install libraries with setupTools/Pip. So it must have not liked the path while installing.

I very happy to be back on track again!!!! :)